Connection to mongodb remote server from windows
Newbie to mongodb, I'm trying to connect to a remote mongodb from my windows laptop, I have installed compass and mongosh.
This is the credentials I've been given :
IP  xx.xx.xxx.xxx
MongoDB (access)    user: "user",pwd: "pwd", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
MongoDB (Login) mongo -u user -p --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB (re7 database)  db
Firewall    ufw => rules => allow IP yy.yy.yyy.yyy

I'm getting a connection timeout while running the following (or trying to connect via compass) :
mongosh "mongodb://user:pwd@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:27017/db" --authenticationDatabase admin
Is this something to do with the firewall rule, what am I supposed with it?
Thanks for your help

Is the MongoDB running? Does it bind all IP's?

If you get a timeout error (rather than a connection refused error), then most likely the firewall still blocks the connection. Do you have a network firewall in between? Did you allow port 27017? Did you allow incoming or outgoing connections?

Problem was indeed the firewall !
